# scala: how to get a maximun value of a column in a data frame

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I'm trying to get aggregation value of the column in a DataFrame like this:

`+----+---+
|  v1| v2|
+----+---+
|-1.0|  0|
| 0.0|  1|
| 1.0|  2|
|-2.0|  3|
+----+---+`

I have tried with agg max function of spark but, doesn't works like i need.

I want to get a maximum value absolute: e.g in the column v1 is -2.0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way is to make a struct with "(abs(value),value)" and then maximize this, but take second field to get original value back:

```
df
 .select(
   max(struct(abs($"v1"),$"v1")).as("maxabs")
  )
 .select($"maxabs.v1")
 .show() // or .as[Double].first
```

Comment: Thanks! Can i do this for all the columns of the DataFrame?How?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this something like this.

```
scala> df.show
+----+---+
|  v1| v2|
+----+---+
|-1.0|  0|
| 0.0|  1|
| 1.0|  2|
|-2.0|  3|
+----+---+


scala> df.join(df.select(max(abs(col("v1"))).as("v3")),abs(col("v1")) === col("v3"),"inner").select(col("v1")).show
+----+
|  v1|
+----+
|-2.0|
+----+
```

Comment: this will return 2.0, not -2.0

Comment: @RaphaelRoth you are right. I will edit my answer. Thanks for pointing this !

Comment: @RaphaelRoth Updated. Not the optimised one. I like your answer more though :)

Answer (score 0):

you can do something like this as well,

```
df.map(r => abs(r.get(0).toString.toDouble)).agg(org.apache.spark.sql.functions.max(col("value"))).show
```

```
+----------+
|max(value)|
+----------+
|       2.0|
+----------+
```